# can users manipulate what is being sent to web server via POST array in PHP?

Tags: php

We know that if we pass some values via GET method we will  see the value in the url during the operation. I guess that developers have created POST to make that passing of values to be invisible so make the applications more secure. If I am incorrect please  correct me since I am curious about that.

So here is my question.
Is there a way that users have access to what is being sent via that POST associative array?  I think maybe it might be possible since what is sent is sent from the client's machine.

Comment: That's not the purpose of POST at all. POST is not more secure than GET (though naively you might think so as data won't show up in a typical browser's address bar, that's hardly "security")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I make a guess that developers have created POST for making that passing values to be invisible so make the applications more secure

No. POST requests are designed to be non-repeatable. i.e. if you make the same request again, it isn't a given that you'll get the same result. It is for things such as adding a comment to a forum, placing an order or changing an address.

The data isn't in the URI because it shouldn't be bookmarkable or linked to.

It also allows for large amounts of data to be included and files to be attached.

> Is there a way that users have access to what is beeing sent via that POST associative array?

Absolutely. The client is entirely under the user's control (unless it is running on a locked down machine that the user can't control) and can make whatever HTTP request the user wants.

The most trivial case would be for the user to use a tool such as Firebug to edit the form in the browser before submitting it.

Answer (score 1):

> can users manipalte what is beeing send to web server via POST array in PHP?

Sure. Why not?

POST and get hold different purposes.

- GET is for requesting data from the site.
- POST is for storing data.

So, it is just an accident that you cannot see POST data in the url. However, such a feature can be used for security reasons. Not for hiding something from user but to hide the sensitive data (like password) from browser's history.

Comment: then why POST is created when there is GET ?  And could you please bring an example how do we manipulate that values ?

Comment: I am manipulating POST **right now**, while sending this very comment. Why it was invented is another question, but not to hide anything from the user.

Comment: @NarekMusakhanyan because GET has limitations like size etc. Check this link. http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/methods.html

Comment: I meant this .Yes your comment or whatever you type in text field after you hit submit goes to the server right ?  But how do you know what other values are sent to server via POST ?

Comment: if you are talking of the hidden fields - yes, I know a secret kung-fu of opening an HTML source of the page.

Comment: just confused about kung-fu stuff . Could you explain it a bit particularly ?

Comment: Time to take this to a chatroom. This is a programming Q&A, not a meeting place for mentoring.

Comment: Go yo your browser menu, choose View -> "As HTML" or page source or something. And you will see all the page source with forms, fields and everything

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit  I apologise for making it too long . I should explore POST once more .